# How do I install pgcrypto on Windows?

Tags: postgresql, windows, permissions, psql, pgcrypto

I would like to install `pgcrypto` in Windows. I have a file `C:\Program\PostgreSQL\9.0\share\contrib\pgcrypto.sql` but when I try to run it in `psql` I get an error:

```
C:: Permission denied
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you confirm that the file exists at `C:\Program\PostgreSQL\9.0\share\pgcrypto.sql` and not at `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\share\pgcrypto.sql` for example?

Comment: @Jack: Yes, it's the 64-bit version. I have `C:\Program\PostgreSQL\9.0\lib\pgcrypto.dll` and `C:\Program\PostgreSQL\9.0\share\contrib\pgcrypto.sql`

Comment: I get the same error even if I start the `psql` command prompt as Administrator.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the script line by line into an interactive pg shell and see where you get the error? Or perhaps try it with pgAdmin? Also have you verified the ability to run psql in interactive mode?

Comment: Have you set the whole postgres(not just /bin but everything) directory to be accessible by everyone (or the correct user)? I had the problem once that the access rules were wrong by default.

Comment: Per [here](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2003/09/msg02913.html), you might try adding the -e option to the psql command to get a better error description.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the full error message you receive (I have a hunch you didn't post it in full) you probably are trying to run the script by using a login role which is not superuser:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>c:\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe -U milen -f C:\PostgreSQL\9.0\share\contrib\pgcrypto.sql milen
SET
psql:C:/PostgreSQL/9.0/share/contrib/pgcrypto.sql:9: ERROR:  permission denied for language c
psql:C:/PostgreSQL/9.0/share/contrib/pgcrypto.sql:14: ERROR:  permission denied for language c
psql:C:/PostgreSQL/9.0/share/contrib/pgcrypto.sql:19: ERROR:  permission denied for language c
...
```